# get classic dev mode does not work

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

I am using GWT 2.6.1 and I want to debug my application as it was before in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). 
When I start debugging in Classic Dev Mode, I get a white blank screen on Chrome. When I open debug screen in Chrome, I see the error message : " Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

How can I debug in old fashioned way?

Thx in advance.

HDayi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dev Mode plugin has been deprecated a long time ago for both chrome and firefox.
If you really want to keep using the old dev mode, the only browser that will allow you to use it right now is Internet Explorer.

If you can, you should consider switching to the all new GWT 2.7 which contains significant improvement to the super dev mode that replaces the old hosted mode, with greatly improved recompilation times.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used gwt for long time, lots of things have changed. In 2.7 gwt designer does not work :(